# Samba shares on fuseiso mounts don't work

Tags: ubuntu, samba, ubuntu-12.04, fuse

I've set up a CD-server which gets it's ISOs from a remote fileserver via cifs. To mount those ISOs I use fuseiso.

When I try to connect to such a fuseiso mount I get NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME, if I connect to a share that resides on the CD-server I can connect to it.

Why do the fuseiso mounts not work with Samba? If you need the full log samba creates I'm happy to  post it to pastebin.

```
Server details:
Ubuntu Server 12.04 amd64
Samba 3.6.3
fuse 2.8.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to use the `-oallow_other` option with the `fuseiso mount` command.